# Is it possible to display only one array key from a react component returning an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I’m very new to react and still experimenting to see how I’m going to transition to this new architecture.

Right now, I have a simple component, that I’m returning an array of elements (just for testing purposes):

```
class FrontendCategoriesListing extends Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            [
                <h1>
                    First information
                </h1>,
                <h2>
                    Second information
                </h2>,
                < >
                    Third information
                </ >,
                <div>
                    Fourth information
                </div>
            ]
        );
    }
}

export default FrontendCategoriesListing;
```

In my project, right now I’m able to display all elements fine, wherever I want to. But my goal is to display just one element, if I want to. For example: in some cases, I want only to display:

```
<div>
    Fourth information
</div>
```

The problem is that where I’m using this component, it only displays all elements. I’ve tried to use an array like syntax to display, like [0] or [2], but then it displays nothing. Is there a way to do this using this architecture? Or is there another architecture I should use. It’s very important that I use only one component to pass as many element I want to.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[Here's good info about Heroku filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos)

In a nutshell you can't rely on it.

As a alternative you can use [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/storage/blobs/), [Google Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage).

Another idea would be converting image to dataUrl and put it (with all relevant information about file) in free tier database like [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). Unfortunately that requires additional implementation

Comment: Yeah. I undestand. But as I mentioned, this would be just for studying purposes. But thanks for the info and tips.